# Solving math captcha involving a limit and $\sin(1/x)$

Tags: limits, recreational-mathematics

The other day, while I was accessing a Russian math enthusiast web site, I came across this captcha:

[image]

Can you help me make sense of it, and enter that site?

Comment: Wow! What website is this that makes you solve a math problem in order to enter it? As for the answer, it's $\ln(2)$.

Comment: "Prove that you are human by writing a wrong but well-formed answer."

Comment: $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is bounded, so $\arctan x \cdot sin\frac{1}{x}$ goes to $0$, so the limit is $\ln 2$.
P.S. I'm not sure if you really wanted the solution or just wanted to share this fun detail with us, but I'm gonna act clueless here!

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer Probably a math site lol

Comment: The square root term won't be defined on any neighbourhood of $0$ - does this get in the way of the limit existing?

Comment: @πr8 - Can you elaborate more? Does this limit exist at all?

Comment: Well, viewing the function as being real valued, note that that $\arctan x \sin 1/x$ term will sometimes be negative on any neighbourhood of $x=0$. This means that the square root, and hence the function as a whole, isn't defined around $x=0$. Unless the function is defined in a neighbourhood of $0$, we can't even begin to talk about the limit at $0$ existing.

Comment: Could you show us the link to that page ?.

Comment: @πr8 Whenever it diverges, you can 're-captcha' until you find something trivial or something which converges...!!!

Comment: This is bit audacious and perhaps will likely restrict the website to a limited audience.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$|\arctan(x)\sin(1/x)|<|x|$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\arctan(x)\sin(1/x)=0$$

And

$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(2+\sqrt{\arctan(x)\sin(1/x)}\right)=\ln(2)$$

Comment: Oops, that's not a hint xD

Comment: +1, for your Art of Beautifully using this Simple inequality.

Comment: :D Thanks, I try to follow my username :P

Comment: This uses the relaxed definition of limit where only points of domain of function are considered. It is easy to observe that the function itself is not defined in any deleted neighborhood of $0$ so the usual definition of limit does not apply.

Answer (score 7):

Since $$\lim_{x \to 0} (\arctan x)=0 \tag1$$

and

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sin \left(\frac 1x \right) \mbox{ is oscillatory, but} \sin \left(\frac 1x \right)\in [-1,1] \tag2$$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$ , $$\lim_{x \to 0}  \left[(\arctan x) \cdot \sin \left(\frac 1x \right) \right]=0 $$
Therefore:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(2+\sqrt{\arctan(x)\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}~\right)=\boxed{\ln(2)}$$

Comment: +1 preferably, I would write $-1\le\sin(1/x)\le1$ rather than having a limit attached to it.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  I think it seems to better now.Does it?

Comment: Yeah, looks good :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of accuracy, I want to add that other answers are correct if it is assumed that the limit in question is [one-sided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit). In other words, they show:

$$\lim_{x\to{0^+}}\ ln\left(2+\sqrt{\arctan(x)\sin(1/x)}\right)=\ln(2)$$

(notice the plus sign in $x\to{0^+}$)

However (see the comments to the question and to the answers), it is clear that the two-sided limit does not exist.